# Why don't torrent leeching sites leech video files to complete 100%?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, bittorrent-sync

I downloaded `.mp4` file using torrent leeching sites.
After checking the downloaded data with torrent file, it shows only `99.9%` (no problem with playback)

[image]

It only for videos files, but for `zip/exe` files etc it's leeching 100%.

Comment: As long as it is a playable video with no missing parts, who cares.